# why i am getting this error when installing REACT?

Tags: reactjs

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUbIp.png)

I tryed to clear the cache, didn t work. i also reinstalled node and visual studio and still getting this error

Comment: That probably means your `package.json` is corrupt / not plain text.

Comment: i have corrupted files in npm -cache. when i try to delete them i can't. i also tryed to delete them via command prompt and it s not working

Comment: Have you tried deleting your node_modules directory and re-running 'npm install'?